# jQuery get current view position from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position

I wish to check if my current element is in view or not. I use this condition to check that:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.element').offset().top) {
    //show
}
```

But problem is that `$(window).scrollTop()` is giving different results on different browser height (I'm using FireFox, first number is `.scrollTop()`, second - `.offset().top`):

[image]

now I just reduce height of firebug (so scroll bar is decreased in size):

[image]

So I can't use `$(window).scrollTop()` to get how mush I have scrolled in page.
Any other way how to define if element is in view?

Comment: There are few plugins that are useful to detect if an element is "in viewport". These ones are very nice: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview. For example the first one lets you create such things: `$('someselector').is(':appeared')`

Comment: Yes, this plugin can be good, i would just consider having 4kb (or ~1.5kb minified) of code just to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to consider these 4 base values:

- Window's height
- Window's scroll top
- Element's offset top
- Element's height

Based on that, you will have:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var elementHeight = $(".element").height();
var elementOffsetTop = $(".element").offset().top;

if ((elementOffsetTop <= windowScrollTop + windowHeight) && (elementOffsetTop + elementHeight >= windowScrollTop))
    console.log('Visible on viewport');
```

Note that with this algorithm, you will be able to check if the element is visible on the viewport, independent of its height, and most importantly, considering the case when you scroll the window beyond the element.

It will say that the element is visible when the highest part or the lowest part of the element is shown on viewport.